# Get a dict between tags from html request

Tags: python, html, json, parsing, html-parsing

just wondering how you would be able to get usable data from between tags from a html request. Assume this is in some html, how would I extract the dict to use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"static_root":"\/\/d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net\/bluebar\/a1968ef","platform":{"is_touch":false,"app_platform":"web"},"hostname":"instagram.com","entry_data":{"DesktopPPage":[{"canSeePrerelease":false,"viewer":null,"media":{"caption_is_edited":false,"code":"vF25LwCnL8","date":1415348305.0,"video_url":"http:\/\/videos-h-12.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xap1\/10753251_876245142395032_328159772_n.mp4","caption":"2014 season teaser! Just a taste of some of the \ud83d\udd28\ud83d\udd28\ud83d\udd28 that got fumbled on \ud83d\udcf9 this season. Edit dropping fall 2017 @m.wilkie @sturhyssmith #snowboarding #springshred #bdpproteam #turoaparks #turoa #mtruapehu #seasonedit #wouldyouratherfightagoatwithahumanheadorahumanwithagoathead?","secure_video_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-videos-h-12-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xap1\/10753251_876245142395032_328159772_n.mp4","usertags":{"nodes":[]},"comments":{"nodes":[{"text":"Where do I buy tickets to the London premiere? #fanboy","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"848487057151652334","user":{"username":"jamesbutchernz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg"}},{"text":"It's invites only @jamesbutchernz @m.wilkie is choosing too so chances are slim unless your smoking hot with low self esteem.","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849353938720944684","user":{"username":"bobeykrebner","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg"}},{"text":"It's lucky we all know I'm both of those. #easy","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849403857951420829","user":{"username":"jamesbutchernz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg"}},{"text":"Last I heard you were smoking hot and had the self esteem of Kanye West @jamesbutchernz what changed?","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849671858500038887","user":{"username":"bobeykrebner","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg"}},{"text":"You know what they say @bobeykrebner. Treat yourself like Kayne treats Kayne.","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849966794608898266","user":{"username":"jamesbutchernz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg"}}]},"shared_by_author":true,"likes":{"count":41,"viewer_has_liked":false,"nodes":[{"user":{"username":"claytonbenson","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_52633025_75sq_1359351765.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"snowrev","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10735284_1474262932842435_1018554144_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"shayning_","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10817775_319647074907693_836092401_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"paused_future","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpa1\/10809941_1580815445475533_469492417_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"kris_tayl0r","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10802916_384369668395220_1244229274_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"crazyshuz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfp1\/10787707_905860216092359_425635869_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"titstatertots","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10554089_855164584513369_706239607_a.jpg"}}]},"owner":{"username":"bobeykrebner","requested_by_viewer":false,"followed_by_viewer":false,"profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg","has_blocked_viewer":false,"id":"1459690667","is_private":false},"is_video":true,"id":"848325528968131324","display_src":"http:\/\/photos-e.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfp1\/10748245_307748359428196_942078105_n.jpg"},"__get_params":{},"staticRoot":"\/\/d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net\/bluebar\/a1968ef","__query_string":"?","prerelease":false,"__path":"\/p\/vF25LwCnL8\/","shortcode":"vF25LwCnL8"}]},"country_code":"AU","config":{"viewer":null,"csrf_token":"0bfa16595bdacb5bcfcb94441d0fb7ab"}};</script>
```

I basically want to know how to get the usable data from within the script tags but after the `"window._sharedData ="` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a combination of HTML parsing and text manipulation.

BeautifulSoup would help with the parsing, after which you can extract the `<script>` tag text content and split out the JavaScript object definition:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page_source)
script_tag = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('window\._sharedData'))
shared_data = script_tag.string.partition('=')[-1].strip(' ;')
```

The last line takes the string contents of the tag, splits off everything up to the first `=` then removes all leading and trailing whitespace and semicolons.

Demo, including loading the resulting string as JSON:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"static_root":"\/\/d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net\/bluebar\/a1968ef","platform":{"is_touch":false,"app_platform":"web"},"hostname":"instagram.com","entry_data":{"DesktopPPage":[{"canSeePrerelease":false,"viewer":null,"media":{"caption_is_edited":false,"code":"vF25LwCnL8","date":1415348305.0,"video_url":"http:\/\/videos-h-12.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xap1\/10753251_876245142395032_328159772_n.mp4","caption":"2014 season teaser! Just a taste of some of the \ud83d\udd28\ud83d\udd28\ud83d\udd28 that got fumbled on \ud83d\udcf9 this season. Edit dropping fall 2017 @m.wilkie @sturhyssmith #snowboarding #springshred #bdpproteam #turoaparks #turoa #mtruapehu #seasonedit #wouldyouratherfightagoatwithahumanheadorahumanwithagoathead?","secure_video_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-videos-h-12-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xap1\/10753251_876245142395032_328159772_n.mp4","usertags":{"nodes":[]},"comments":{"nodes":[{"text":"Where do I buy tickets to the London premiere? #fanboy","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"848487057151652334","user":{"username":"jamesbutchernz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg"}},{"text":"It's invites only @jamesbutchernz @m.wilkie is choosing too so chances are slim unless your smoking hot with low self esteem.","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849353938720944684","user":{"username":"bobeykrebner","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg"}},{"text":"It's lucky we all know I'm both of those. #easy","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849403857951420829","user":{"username":"jamesbutchernz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg"}},{"text":"Last I heard you were smoking hot and had the self esteem of Kanye West @jamesbutchernz what changed?","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849671858500038887","user":{"username":"bobeykrebner","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg"}},{"text":"You know what they say @bobeykrebner. Treat yourself like Kayne treats Kayne.","viewer_can_delete":false,"id":"849966794608898266","user":{"username":"jamesbutchernz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg"}}]},"shared_by_author":true,"likes":{"count":41,"viewer_has_liked":false,"nodes":[{"user":{"username":"claytonbenson","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_52633025_75sq_1359351765.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"snowrev","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10735284_1474262932842435_1018554144_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"shayning_","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10817775_319647074907693_836092401_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"paused_future","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpa1\/10809941_1580815445475533_469492417_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"kris_tayl0r","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10802916_384369668395220_1244229274_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"crazyshuz","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfp1\/10787707_905860216092359_425635869_a.jpg"}},{"user":{"username":"titstatertots","profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10554089_855164584513369_706239607_a.jpg"}}]},"owner":{"username":"bobeykrebner","requested_by_viewer":false,"followed_by_viewer":false,"profile_pic_url":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg","has_blocked_viewer":false,"id":"1459690667","is_private":false},"is_video":true,"id":"848325528968131324","display_src":"http:\/\/photos-e.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfp1\/10748245_307748359428196_942078105_n.jpg"},"__get_params":{},"staticRoot":"\/\/d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net\/bluebar\/a1968ef","__query_string":"?","prerelease":false,"__path":"\/p\/vF25LwCnL8\/","shortcode":"vF25LwCnL8"}]},"country_code":"AU","config":{"viewer":null,"csrf_token":"0bfa16595bdacb5bcfcb94441d0fb7ab"}};</script>
... ''')
>>> script_tag = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('window\._sharedData'))
>>> shared_data = script_tag.string.partition('=')[-1].strip(' ;')
>>> import json
>>> result = json.loads(shared_data)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
{u'config': {u'csrf_token': u'0bfa16595bdacb5bcfcb94441d0fb7ab',
             u'viewer': None},
 u'country_code': u'AU',
 u'entry_data': {u'DesktopPPage': [{u'__get_params': {},
                                    u'__path': u'/p/vF25LwCnL8/',
                                    u'__query_string': u'?',
                                    u'canSeePrerelease': False,
                                    u'media': {u'caption': u'2014 season teaser! Just a taste of some of the \U0001f528\U0001f528\U0001f528 that got fumbled on \U0001f4f9 this season. Edit dropping fall 2017 @m.wilkie @sturhyssmith #snowboarding #springshred #bdpproteam #turoaparks #turoa #mtruapehu #seasonedit #wouldyouratherfightagoatwithahumanheadorahumanwithagoathead?',
                                               u'caption_is_edited': False,
                                               u'code': u'vF25LwCnL8',
                                               u'comments': {u'nodes': [{u'id': u'848487057151652334',
                                                                         u'text': u'Where do I buy tickets to the London premiere? #fanboy',
                                                                         u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg',
                                                                                   u'username': u'jamesbutchernz'},
                                                                         u'viewer_can_delete': False},
                                                                        {u'id': u'849353938720944684',
                                                                         u'text': u"It's invites only @jamesbutchernz @m.wilkie is choosing too so chances are slim unless your smoking hot with low self esteem.",
                                                                         u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg',
                                                                                   u'username': u'bobeykrebner'},
                                                                         u'viewer_can_delete': False},
                                                                        {u'id': u'849403857951420829',
                                                                         u'text': u"It's lucky we all know I'm both of those. #easy",
                                                                         u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg',
                                                                                   u'username': u'jamesbutchernz'},
                                                                         u'viewer_can_delete': False},
                                                                        {u'id': u'849671858500038887',
                                                                         u'text': u'Last I heard you were smoking hot and had the self esteem of Kanye West @jamesbutchernz what changed?',
                                                                         u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg',
                                                                                   u'username': u'bobeykrebner'},
                                                                         u'viewer_can_delete': False},
                                                                        {u'id': u'849966794608898266',
                                                                         u'text': u'You know what they say @bobeykrebner. Treat yourself like Kayne treats Kayne.',
                                                                         u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_1052126311_75sq_1391324963.jpg',
                                                                                   u'username': u'jamesbutchernz'},
                                                                         u'viewer_can_delete': False}]},
                                               u'date': 1415348305.0,
                                               u'display_src': u'http://photos-e.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xfp1/10748245_307748359428196_942078105_n.jpg',
                                               u'id': u'848325528968131324',
                                               u'is_video': True,
                                               u'likes': {u'count': 41,
                                                          u'nodes': [{u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_52633025_75sq_1359351765.jpg',
                                                                                u'username': u'claytonbenson'}},
                                                                     {u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/10735284_1474262932842435_1018554144_a.jpg',
                                                                                u'username': u'snowrev'}},
                                                                     {u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/10817775_319647074907693_836092401_a.jpg',
                                                                                u'username': u'shayning_'}},
                                                                     {u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10809941_1580815445475533_469492417_a.jpg',
                                                                                u'username': u'paused_future'}},
                                                                     {u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/10802916_384369668395220_1244229274_a.jpg',
                                                                                u'username': u'kris_tayl0r'}},
                                                                     {u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/10787707_905860216092359_425635869_a.jpg',
                                                                                u'username': u'crazyshuz'}},
                                                                     {u'user': {u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/10554089_855164584513369_706239607_a.jpg',
                                                                                u'username': u'titstatertots'}}],
                                                          u'viewer_has_liked': False},
                                               u'owner': {u'followed_by_viewer': False,
                                                          u'has_blocked_viewer': False,
                                                          u'id': u'1459690667',
                                                          u'is_private': False,
                                                          u'profile_pic_url': u'https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/10584664_742398385822158_510451676_a.jpg',
                                                          u'requested_by_viewer': False,
                                                          u'username': u'bobeykrebner'},
                                               u'secure_video_url': u'https://igcdn-videos-h-12-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/10753251_876245142395032_328159772_n.mp4',
                                               u'shared_by_author': True,
                                               u'usertags': {u'nodes': []},
                                               u'video_url': u'http://videos-h-12.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xap1/10753251_876245142395032_328159772_n.mp4'},
                                    u'prerelease': False,
                                    u'shortcode': u'vF25LwCnL8',
                                    u'staticRoot': u'//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/a1968ef',
                                    u'viewer': None}]},
 u'hostname': u'instagram.com',
 u'platform': {u'app_platform': u'web', u'is_touch': False},
 u'static_root': u'//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/a1968ef'}
```

Comment: Legend, that's exactly what I was looking to do! Waiting 3 mins to accept the answer! Thanks mate

Comment: How would I change your answer so It would find the those tags from this url: http://instagram.com/p/vF25LwCnL8/

Comment: @Johnny: the script tag you are looking for is the 7th, so I guess `soup.find_all('script')[6]` would do.

Comment: @Johnny: I updated the answer with a better idea: limiting the search for a script tag with the right assignment target in it.